# Unexpected delay during processing of multiple images using SharpDX/Direct2D before rendering in .NET WinForms application

Tags: .net, winforms, performance, sharpdx, direct2d

I develop a .NET WinForms application and need to scale a lot of big images and display them as small icons on the form. I have problem with performance especially on specific machines. Profiles shows that most time takes GDI+ during scaling these images. Thus my goal now is to use SharpDX to scale these image using Direct2D and to draw them using GDI+ after that as is.
Now I have a test class in which I generate devices and context only once. Then, I pass source and target .NET Bitmaps to the Scale method.

```
Public Sub ScaleImage(pBaseImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap, pTargetImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap)
   FillSourceBitmap(pBaseImage)
   Dim cropEffect = New d2.Effects.Crop(d2dContext)
   cropEffect.SetInput(0, d2SourceBitmap, True)
   cropEffect.Rectangle = New Mathematics.Interop.RawVector4(0, 0, pBaseImage.Width, pBaseImage.Height)
   Dim scaleEffect = New d2.Effects.Scale(d2dContext)
   scaleEffect.SetInput(0, cropEffect.Output, True)
   scaleEffect.ScaleAmount = New SharpDX.Mathematics.Interop.RawVector2(pTargetImage.Width / pBaseImage.Width, pTargetImage.Height / pBaseImage.Height)

   Dim d2TargetBitmapProps = New d2.BitmapProperties1(d2PixelFormat, 96, 96, d2.BitmapOptions.Target)
   Dim d2TargetBitmap = New d2.Bitmap1(d2dContext, New Size2(pTargetImage.Width, pTargetImage.Height), d2TargetBitmapProps)
   d2dContext.Target = d2TargetBitmap
   d2dContext.BeginDraw()
   d2dContext.DrawImage(scaleEffect,)
   d2dContext.EndDraw()

   CopyBitmapFromDxToGDI(d2TargetBitmap, pTargetImage)
End Sub

Private Sub FillSourceBitmap(bmp As Drawing.Bitmap)
   Dim bmpData As Imaging.BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(New Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)
   d2SourceBitmap.CopyFromMemory(bmpData.Scan0, bmpData.Stride,
                           New Mathematics.Interop.RawRectangle(0, 0, bmpData.Width, bmpData.Height))
   bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)
End Sub

Private Sub CopyBitmapFromDxToGDI(bitmap As d2.Bitmap1, bmp As Drawing.Bitmap)
   Dim d2TempBitmapProps = New d2.BitmapProperties1(d2PixelFormat, 96, 96, BitmapOptions.CpuRead Or BitmapOptions.CannotDraw)
   Dim d2TempBitmap = New d2.Bitmap1(d2dContext, New Size2(bmp.Width, bmp.Height), d2TempBitmapProps)      
   d2TempBitmap.CopyFromRenderTarget(d2dContext)
   
   Dim surface = d2TempBitmap.Surface
   Dim dataStream As DataStream = Nothing
   Dim dataRectangle As DataRectangle = surface.Map(dxgi.MapFlags.Read, dataStream)
   Dim bmpData As Imaging.BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(New Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb)

   Dim offset = bmpData.Reserved
   Dim buffer(4) As Byte
   For y As Integer = 0 To surface.Description.Height - 1
      For x As Integer = 0 To surface.Description.Width - 1            
         dataStream.Seek((y * dataRectangle.Pitch) + (x * 4), SeekOrigin.Begin)
         dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4)           
         
         Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, offset, buffer(3))            
         Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, offset+1, buffer(0))
         Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, offset+2, buffer(1))
         Marshal.WriteByte(bmpData.Scan0, offset+3, buffer(2))
         offset += 4
      Next
   Next
   bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)
   surface.Unmap()
   dataStream.Dispose()
   d2TempBitmap.Dispose()
End Sub
```

You can find the full code here https://github.com/Drreamer/Direct2DImageProcessing

Now the code works, but still not fast enough. The profile shows that most time code does not work but some other operations are performed:
[image]

You can see that it takes 10ms to render one image. After that another application thread works for 10ms and after that the application do nothing for 20ms.
Does anybody have an idea what is the cause of the issue and how the solution should be rewroten to resolve the problem?

Comment: You're still using a lot of GDI+ in your code, even when you use Direct2D. Is your goal to display scaled images on the screen (as in the code) or to save them somehow?

Comment: I have complex reports that are rendered using GDI+ in WinForms application. Some of these reports display a lot of images (ordinarily scaled to size about 50x100 from the base images of bigger size). It is impossible to rewrite the rendering code to render everything using Direct2D. Thus I have tried to use Direct2D only to scale images. Another task is to display these images in the HTML report version in the browser, in this case it is necessary to send scaled images to the client to minimize traffic. However, this task is not mentioned in the base question.

Comment: The benefit of using Direct2D in this context is marginal as you do a lot of RAM allocations (for GDI), copies from RAM (GDI bitmaps) to GPU memory (Direct2D bitmaps) and back, and you use GDI to do all the rendering. To really improve performance and use the GPU, you'd have to rewrite more of your code.

Comment: I have reviewed the profile one more time and feel that the problem occurs because some thread is started during(or before, or after) execution of the Direct2D code. And this operation causes the delay. Have not meet similar issues in the past.